# Pattern for cancelling internal stream subscriptions once an object can be deleted?

Tags: dart, listener, resource-cleanup

From my understanding of Dart's `Stream` any listeners will be kept as a reference until `StreamSubscription.cancel()` is called. This means my listening objects will not be removed from memory until the stream is destroyed as well.

Are there any standard patterns to ensure I cancel all internal listeners once I don't need the object anymore? Is this even an issue in Dart or am I misunderstanding the concept?

One solution I can think of would be a `destroy` or `cancelSubscriptions` method that has to be called manually once I know the objects is no longer needed.

Comment: afaik, weak events aren't there in Dart, just like the missing weak sets and weak maps. All those features will surely be added, question is when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subscriber and the instance referencing the stream are both subject to garbage collection (not referenced by some active instance) the connection should not count and both instances should be garbage collected (but I'm not sure about this).

I haven't seen any pattern yet.
When I just want to cancel all subscriptions I store them in a collection and run

```dart
subscriptions.forEach(s) {
  s.cancel();
}
subscriptions.clear();
```

When I want to cancel re-subscribe in different situations I create a variable for each such subscription.

```dart
var someSubscr = xxx.listen(...);

...

if(someSubscr != null) someSubscr.cancel();
someScubscr = null;
```

I used this only in Polymer elements and I use `detached` for unsubscribing and `attached` for subscribing.
When I have the need in other situations I would just put above code into a `dispose` method and call it when I know I won't need the instance anymore.

I think it would be nice to create an interface and implement this for classes that should have a `dispose` method.

```dart
abstract class Disposable {
  void dispose();
}
```

When you have some kind of factory that creates the instances for you and you are not sure whether the instance needs a call to `dispose` when you are finished using it you are on the safe side by just adding this line.

```dart
if(x is Disposable) x.dispose();
```

There is a feature request to make the VM call a destructor or a dispose method

- http://dartbug.com/3691

but it is uncertain this will be implemented.

Also related:

- http://dartbug.com/2143
- http://dartbug.com/18829

Comment: If there is not a standard way of doing it yet I'm happy with doing it my own way. A `Disposable` interface was just what I was thinking of. Thank you once again, fellow Linzer!